# MS SQL Server Optimize repeated column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, storage

I was requested to create a table that will contain many repeated values and I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

I **must** use SQL Server. I would love to use Azure Table Storage and partition keys, but I'm **not allowed to**.

Imagine that the table `Shoes` has the columns

```
id int, customer_name varchar(50), shoe_type varchar(50)
```

The problem is that the column `shoe_type` will have millions of repeated values, and I want to have them in their own partition, but SQL Server only allows ranged partitions afaik.

I don't want the repeated values to take more space than needed, meaning that if the column value is repeated 50 times, I don't want it to take 50 times more space, only 1 time.

I thought about using a relationship between the column `shoe_type` (as an `int`) and another table which will have its string value, but is that the most I can optimize?

**EDIT**

`Shoes` table data

```
id  customer_name   shoe_type
-----------------------------
1   a               nike
2   b               adidas
3   c               adidas
4   d               nike
5   e               adidas
6   f               nike
7   g               puma
8   h               nike
```

As you can see, the rows contain repeated `shoe_type` values (nike, adidas, puma).

What I thought about is using the `shoe_type` column as an `int` foreign key to another table, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, because in Azure Table Storage you have partitions and partition keys, and in MS SQL Server you have partitions, but they are ranged **only**.

Comment: Rather than make us "imagine" data, provide us with some. Post DDL and DML scripts for your sample data, and then post the expected result you are after for said data.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization. Don't "imagine" a problem that does not yet exist.

Comment: If your data is highly repetitive, a (clustered) columnstore index would make short work of it. Whether a CS index will properly support your queries is another matter (but you can combine it with rowstore indexes, of course). Another option is a rowstore index with page compression. If only *one* value is repeated very often and the rest is not, you can use a filtered index to specifically include or exclude it.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks, I've edited the post.

Comment: @SMor, I understand what you're saying, but I've asked for this specific problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thank you. I will look into it and comment in the post what I find.

Comment: @JeroenMostert makes an excellent point. You have repeated values and you don't want them to take up space - use a clustered columnstore index.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks. I've done my reseach about about those indexes and I will be using them. How may I give you an upvote or mark your comment as the solution?

Comment: I reread your question. You're really stuck on Azure table storage there and I'm not sure why. _I thought about using a relationship between the column shoe_type (as an int) and another table which will have its string value, but is that the most I can optimize?_ This is called "normalisation" and this is 100% what you should do as per @Neville answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The sample data you provide suggests that there is a "shoe type" entity in the business domain, and that all shoes have a mandatory relationship to a single shoe type. It would be different if the values were descriptive text - e.g. "Attractive running shoe, suitable for track and leisure wear". Repeated values are often (but of course not always) an indicator that there is another entity you can extract.

You suggest that the table will have millions of records. In very general terms, I recommend designing your schema to reflect the business domain, and only go for exotic optimization options once you know, and can measure, that you have a performance problem.

In your case, I'd suggest factoring out a separate table called "shoe_types", and to include a foreign key relationship from "shoes" to "shoe_types". The primary key for "shoe_types" should be a clustered index, and the "shoe_type_id" in "shoe_types" should be a regular index. All things being equal, with (tens of) millions of rows, that hit the foreign key index should be very fast.

In addition, supporting queries like "find all shoes where shoe type name starts with 'nik%'" should be much faster, because the shoe_types table should have far fewer rows than "shoes".